# Autocomplete loader continues spinning if no results found

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, magento, autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI to do an autocomplete on a input field - it works as expected when I have valid data it can match to, however if it cannot match a search term to something in the database the ajax spinners just continue spinning?

How would I amend this so if a user enters a term that cannot be matched after x amount of seconds it will stop the spinner & display a 'organisation cannot be found' within the transformResult function?

```
// error in console.log
suggestions is undefined
```

The actual jQuery code for the autocomplete is below:

```
$('#org_search_term, #org_search_postcode').autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('rp/organisation/search', array('_secure' => true)) ?>',
        paramName:'term',
        minChars: 3,
        deferRequestBy: 500,
        dataType: 'json',
        onSearchStart: function(){
            $('#org_search_term, #org_search_postcode').addClass('loading');
        },
        onSearchComplete: function(){
            $('#org_search_term, #org_search_postcode').removeClass('loading');
        },
        onSearchError: function(){
            $('#org_search_term, #org_search_postcode').removeClass('loading');
        },
        onSelect: function(selected, data) {

        },
        transformResult: function (response) {

            var results = { suggestions:[] };

            if (!response.totalRecords)
                return false;

            $.each(response.items, function(i, item){
                results.suggestions.push({
                    value: item.organisation_name+', '+item.street+', '+item.town+', '+item.county+', '+item.postcode+', '+item.country,
                    data:  item.organisation_id,
                    organisation_name: item.organisation_name
                });
            });

            // add the catch all result
            results.suggestions.push({
                value: '<?php echo $this->__('My org is not listed') ?>',
                data: null,
                organisation_name: null
            });

            return results;
        }
    });
```